# Is it possible to add an additional layer of authentication to a Jabber (XMPP) server?

Tags: security, xmpp

I'm thinking of making a Jabber (XMPP) server but I need to know if it's possible to add a security token (similar to that of PayPal Verisign keychains) that expires periodically and gets replaces with a new one as an authentication factor. Something like an extension or plugin.

Comment: XMPP uses SASL authentication, so any protocol that has a SASL mechanism should be usable.  (Of course, you'll then need to make sure that the XMPP client implements that SASL mechanism as well.)